# Почему условие выдает ошибку?

Tags: javascript

Как вообще проверять условия я чет запуталса подскажите

```
if (typeof window.art === undefined) {
window.art = new Array();
}
if (window.art[1] === undefined) {
    console.log('ok')
} else {
    console.log('no')
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `typeof` возвращает **строку**, указывающую тип операнда.

```js
if (typeof window.art === 'undefined') {
  window.art = new Array();
}

if (window.art[1] === undefined) {
  console.log('ok')
} else {
  console.log('no')
}
```

Comment: спасибо я понял